# jQuery slide menu jittery behavior when rapid mouse hover

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

so I managed to create a setTimout slideUp/Down function for a menu that works great - but on certain occasions when the user hovers over links, and over their child links it rapidly slides up and down - I know this question is typical but I have tried different things unsuccessfully.

Here's a working demo - you can see if you mouse over the links the function goes nuts
http://jsfiddle.net/eA2HL/2/

```
jQuery('.nav.mainmenu > li').each(function() {
    var t = null;
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var result = jQuery('#result');
    $this.hover(function() {
        t = setTimeout(function() {
            if($this.find('ul').length > 0) {
                result.slideDown(200, function() {
                    if($this.is(':visible')) {
                        $this.find('ul').show();
                    }
                });
            }
            t = null;
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        if (t) {
            clearTimeout(t);
            t = null;
        } else {
            $this.find('ul').hide(0);
            result.slideUp(333, function() {
                $this.find('ul').hide(0);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Reedited my answer as an issue appeared pointed out by @Geeo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.stop(1,1)` (same as `.stop( true , true )`) will help to clear some animation buildups:

```
jQuery('.nav.mainmenu > li').each(function() {
        var t = null;
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        var result = jQuery('#result');
        $this.hover(function() {
            t = setTimeout(function() {
                if($this.find('ul').length > 0) {
                    result.stop(1,1).slideDown(200, function() {  // HERE
                        if($this.is(':visible')) {
                            $this.find('ul').show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                t = null;
            }, 300);
        }, function() {
            if (t) {
                clearTimeout(t);
                t = null;
            } else {
                $this.find('ul').hide(0);
                result.slideUp(333, function() { 
                    $this.find('ul').hide(0);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/eA2HL/13/)**

Comment: stop(1) eh?? didnt know you could do that

Comment: @JeffJones :) well now you know! Hope was useful.

Comment: this doesn't work when you pass from one menu item to another without going out with the mouse

Comment: @Geeo True. http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/eA2HL/13/ reedited. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: has anyone tested this in Firefox? getting some weird results - thanks for your help though!!!

Comment: In firefox works for me! Eventually you can change stop(1,1) to stop(false,true) if you want to experiment a little:)

Answer (score 1):

You can also check is "result" being animated like this (if animated don't animate ):

```
 if($(result).is(':animated')){
  return false;
  }
```